# Perl 6 regex not terminated

Tags: regex, raku

I have a Perl 6 code where I am doing the following:

```
if ($line ~~ /^\s*#/) { print "matches\n"; }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
===SORRY!===
Regex not terminated.
at line 2
------> <BOL>�<EOL>
Unable to parse regex; couldn't find final '/'
at line 2
------> <BOL>�<EOL>
    expecting any of:
        infix stopper
```

This is part of a Perl 5 code:

```
if ($line =~ /^\s*#/)
```

It used to work fine to identify lines that have an optional space and a `#`.

What's causing this error in Perl 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash `#` is used as a comment marker in Perl 6 regexes.

Add a backslash `\` to escape it like this

```
if ( $line =~ /^\s*\#/ )
```

Answer (score 8):

In Perl 6, everything from a lone<sup>1</sup> `#` to the end of the line is considered a comment, even inside regexes.

To avoid this, make it a string literal by placing it inside quotes:

```perl6
if $line ~~ / ^ \s* '#' / { say "matches"; }
```

(Escaping with `\` should also work, but [Rakudo seems to have a parsing bug](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132666) which makes that not work when preceded by a space.
And quoting the character as shown here is the recommended way anyway – Perl 6 specifically introduced quoted strings inside regexes and made spaces insignificant by default, in order to avoid the backslash clutter that many Perl 5 regexes suffer from.)

More generally, *all* non-alphanumeric characters need to be quoted or escaped inside Perl 6 regexes in order to match them literally.
This is another deliberate non-backwards-compatible change from Perl 5, where this is a bit more complicated.
In Perl 6 there is a simple rule:

- alphanumeric --> matches literally only when *not* escaped.
  <sup>(When escaped, they either have special meanings, e.g. `\s` etc., or are forbidden.)</sup>
- non-alphanumeric --> matches literally only when escaped.
  <sup>(When not escaped, they either have special meanings, e.g. `.`, `+`, `#`, etc., or are forbidden.)</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> 'Lone' meaning not part of a larger token such as a quoted string or the opener of an [embedded comment](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Multi-line_/_embedded_comments).*

Comment: A hash within a regex signals a comment only until the next newline or the end of the pattern, whichever comes first.

Comment: *"you pretty much had to memorize the whole list"*. No. You can escape every non-word character quite safely if you wish. That is what `quotemeta` does after all.

Comment: @Borodin "A hash within a regex signals a comment only until the next newline or the end of the pattern, whichever comes first." Are you speaking of P5? I'm pretty sure that in P6 "a lone `#`" works as smls says. (I've added a footnote to smls' answer to cover [an embedded comment](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Multi-line_/_embedded_comments) but that's a minor detail -- smls may decide to revert my edit so I've left the link explaining that minor detail here in this comment too.)

Comment: @Borodin "You can escape every non-word character quite safely if you wish." But you have to decide to do it. Imo [the specific rules](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) in P5 are complex, and you have to either know them to know whether you need to apply `quotemeta`, or just apply `quotemeta` every time you're not sure.

Comment: @Borodin: Fair enough. I've updated the answer to weaken that claim about Perl 5.